# How to get back deleted file in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We had a file in our repository that we deleted several revisions ago. How do we get it back using TortoiseSVN without reverting our entire repository?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to the Show Log screen, and search for the revision when the file was deleted, then right click the file and select **Save revision to...**

[image: tortoiseundelete.jpg]

Comment: But this will lose the file history. Better to use the repository browser and from there use "copy to wc". That way the file history is preverved.
Or another way: revert only the revision where the file was removed (4 entries above the "Save revision to..." in your screenshort).

Comment: Thank for the tip about the "copye to wc" function that saves the history !

Answer (score 8):

The other answers appear to focus on restoring an entire *revision* (using a different location), so here's how to only restore a single file, without having to check out an entire revision, using TortoiseSVN:

1. Open the revision log for the revision that deleted the file.
2. Find the file in the changelist.
3. Right-click the file and select "Revert changes from this revision...". Answer yes.

The file is restored and re-added to the repository. I am not 100% certain if Subversion will treat it as a different file, or as a new revision of the file.

Comment: Terminology: a 'revision' means the change represented by a single commit, not a complete checkout at the time the revision was made.

Answer (score 2):

In the repo browser, there is a menu that says some to the effect of goto version. From here you can browse the field that was available in that revision and drag and drop the file out. i would check the actual program bur I'm currently on my phone.

Hope this helps

Comment: I followed your instructions but instead of dragging&drop i chose "Save to Working Copy" from the context menu

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the revision number where the file was deleted (using the repository browser is probably the easiest way to find this). Do a check out to a new location before that revision.

Answer (score 0):

use revert option or open cmd window and type : 
(give the local path where you've checkout your code) svn -r (type revision no. before deleting that path)